# Disable auto hashing of password while login - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, hash

Is there anyway to change or disable the auto hashing password in laravel while login? According to their documentation,

> The user will be retrieved by the value of the email column. If the
>   user is found, the hashed password stored in the database will be
>   compared with the  password value passed to the method via the array.
>   You should not hash the password specified as the password value,
>   since the framework will automatically hash the value before comparing
>   it to the hashed password in the database. If the two hashed passwords
>   match an authenticated session will be started for the user.

Since it clearly says the framework will auto hash the password and we (developers) should not hash the password while login. What I want is to manually hash the password from the user input and then compare it with the stored hash password in DB. Any idea what changes I have to make in framework or where?

I am using below code to authenticate users. (I have two types of users Buyers and Sellers).

```
 (Auth::guard('buyer')->attempt(['buyerData_primaryemail' => $request->emailOrNumber, 
    'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember')))

(Auth::guard('seller')->attempt(['sellerData_primaryemail' => $request->emailOrNumber, 
    'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember')))
```

Comment: If you hash user's input on login, you wouldn't be able to compare it with stored hash.

Comment: @Tpojka please read my question. Cant understand what you are trying to say in your comment.

Comment: Let me ask you few questions to understand better what is going on here: have you disabled hashing on register, in other words are passwords saved in plain text format?

Comment: I just want to edit the default login function so it doesnt automatically convert the password to hash when it tries to compare the password with stored database password while login.

Comment: If you do that it can't be compared to hashed value stored when registered. That's my point. Or, with DB stored hash [made on registration] only plain text that matches to actual password can be compared with.

Comment: I manually want to convert the plain text using Hash::make function. Just want to disable the auto hashing and want to manully use hash::make function while login.

Comment: I am not sure what should be done here because default functionality works very well. If you explain bit more why would you do this, because it doesn't seem right from security point of view...